# why my callable cloud function will always fail even though it is finished with status code 200?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

so I have callable cloud function like this

```
exports.callableModeratorSendNotification = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {

        const platform = data.platform
        const priority = data.priority
        const message =  data.message
        const moderatorID = context.auth.uid

        // check if moderator have authorization to  send notification and check if moderator is active or not
        const moderatorSnapshot = await db.doc(`moderators/${moderatorID}`).get()
        const moderator = moderatorSnapshot.data()

        if ( !moderator.canSendNotification || !moderator.isActive) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-moderator', 'Moderator is invalid. only active moderator who has authorization that can verify a user.')
        }

        let query

        const now = new Date()
        const xMonthsAgo = moment().subtract(1,"months").toDate()


        query = db.collection(`devices`)
        .where("lastActivity","<=",now)
        .where("lastActivity",">=",xMonthsAgo)

        if ( platform !== "All") {
            query = query.where("platform","==",platform) // iOS or Android
        }

        const devicesQuerySnapshot = await query.get()

        devicesQuerySnapshot.docs.forEach( deviceSnapshot => {

            const device = deviceSnapshot.data()
            console.log(device.userID)



        })

        {result: 'success'}


    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        return null
    }



})
```

at the moment, that function is just to log the user ID. and that function will return 200 code like this in console

[image]

but the problem is in the client side.... I am using Android to call that function, like this

```
fun sendNotification(platform: String, priority: String, message: String) : Task<String> {

        // Create the arguments to the callable function.
        val data = hashMapOf(
            "platform" to platform,
            "priority" to priority,
            "message" to message
        )

        return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("callableModeratorSendNotification")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                val result = task.result?.data as String
                result
            }

    }
```

and then use it like this

```
sendNotification(selectedPlatform,selectedPriority,message).addOnSuccessListener {

    toast("successful")

}.addOnFailureListener {

    toast("failed")
}
```

the problem is, even though the status code in the console is 200, but `addOnFailureListener` will always be called. I expect `addOnSuccessListener` will be called if the response is 200

here is the exception caught by the failure listener

> java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String 2020-02-04
>   11:30:09.023 26024-26024/com.
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

in this line ?

```
val result = task.result?.data as String
```

where does the result come from. does it represent the `return` on my callable function ? I assume callable function should return a promise like cloud function trigger

Comment: What happens if instead of doing `return null` you do `return {result: 'success'}`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I change it as per your request to be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ9Tl.png , and the result is still exactly the same

Comment: What is the exception caught by the failure listener?

Comment: The failure listener receives an exception as its only argument - you should capture that and log it for details.

Comment: @DougStevenson @ samthecodingman I have added the exception on the my question above

Comment: I understand now, the problem is in the result of my callable function which is not string, but on my Android I cast it as a string. I assume the callable function should return a promise like trigger function

Comment: You can't cast a Map to a String.  You will have to deal with the Map as you would normally - get its keys and values. If your function returns a JavaScript object, it will show up as a Map in an Android client, so you should be prepared for that.